# Laravel blade: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to shorthand if statement inside HTML tag in Laravel blade file in this way:

```
<x-checkbox name="enable" id="enable" {{ ($settings->enable) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
    {{ __('Enable') }}
</x-checkbox>
```

But its getting this error `syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF)`. I looked into similar questions and tried the solutions, but still getting same error. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Edit: Checkbox component

```
<label class="inline-flex items-center mt-3">
    <input
        {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-checkbox h-5 w-5 rounded text-indigo-600']) }}
        name="{{ $name }}"
        id="{{ $name }}"
        type="checkbox"
        >
    <span class="ml-2 text-gray-900 text-md font-medium">{{ $slot }}</span>
</label>
```

Comment: can you show checkbox  component and also entire code of this  blade file. Mentioned code doesn't tell where is if condition

Comment: Checkbox component added

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erorr thrown for this line

```
<x-checkbox name="enable" id="enable" {{ ($settings->enable) ? 'checked' : '' }}>
```

So change

```
  <x-checkbox name="enable" id="enable" checked="{{$settings->enable}}">
        {{ __('Enable') }}
    </x-checkbox>
```

then in component

```
@props([
'checked'=>false,

])
     <label class="inline-flex items-center mt-3">
            <input
                {{ $attributes->merge(['class' => 'form-checkbox h-5 w-5 rounded text-indigo-600']) }}
                name="{{ $name }}"
                id="{{ $name }}"
                type="checkbox"  {{$checked?'checked':''}}
            >
            <span class="ml-2 text-gray-900 text-md font-medium">{{ $slot }}</span>
        </label>
```

Comment: It works. Thanks... Component requires more logic. Did not know that.